# How to update my local branch in Git

Tags: git, github

I am really confused using git. Suppose in a repo I have a master branch `master` used between several users and I have created a test branch `test`. From time to time I would `test` to get updates from `master` so that I am always using latest codebase. To do that, I have following options:

In test branch

```
1. git pull origin master

2. git rebase master 

3. git rebase origin/master
```

I do not see any issues with option 1. However option 2  will not work always. It is a local master it will not be updated until I got to `master` branch and do `git pull`. How about option 3? Does `git rebase` internally calls `git fetch` to make sure origin/master is updated? Otherwise this one is also not a good idea right?

Comment: I think you expect #2 to do a `git pull --rebase` (which does a `git fetch` and then rebases the changes into your local copy).  I am not the best person to give you an example of this though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that what you want to do is most simply and sensibly accomplished by #1, as you have observed.

One use for rebase is to control the appearance of the revision history.   Have you read this description here:

http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Rebasing

You haven't said anything that indicates you care about this, in which case I can't see why you would bother.   If you do want to do it, you need to do git pull --rebase, as first noted by Sam Sullivan in comment.

Answer (score 1):

Try this workflow:

1. git pull origin master
2. Make your changes
3. git push origin master

The `pull` does a `fetch` and a `merge`, so that will update your local copy.

Comment: I wonder if there is a foolproof way to use `git rebase` since a lot of people favor it over `git pull`

Comment: There is a debate about which is better, and it really depends on several factors. But the better comparison is `rebase` vs `merge` (rather than `pull`).

Answer (score 1):

The [git book](http://git-scm.com/book/en/) has a decent [tutorial on branching and merging](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging). Take a look and see if that makes it clearer. Basically, you create a new branch using `git checkout -b Richeek1`, which will branch from master's current state. After pulling, to resync Richeek1 with master, `git merge master` will do the trick. Let me know if you have further problems.

Comment: I think `git merge master` will not work until I checkout master branch and do a `git pull` there...